# Execute several commands through ssh with local and remote values

Tags: bash, ssh, heredoc

I am writing a script to match local values with remote ones. As of now, my code is functional and looks like this :

```
#!bin/bash

MY_ARRAY=('value1' 'value2' 'value3' 'wrongValue)
for VALUE in "${MY_ARRAY[@]}"
do
    if [[ $VALUE =~ ^v ]] ; then
        echo "$VALUE : $(ssh admin@machine matching_function $VALUE)" >> output.file
    else
        echo "$VALUE : this is a wrong value" >> output.file
    fi
done
```

The only problem is that for every iteration of the loop, it creates and closes a new ssh connection. As my original dataset is quite big, it takes a long time to execute.

I was looking for a way to optimize this, and read about passing multiline commands to ssh with `ssh admin@machine <<EOF` and adapted my code:

```
MY_ARRAY=('value1' 'value2' 'value3' 'wrongValue)
ssh admin@machine << EOF
    for VALUE in "${MY_ARRAY[@]}"
    do
        if [[ $VALUE =~ ^v ]] ; then
            echo "$VALUE : $(matching_function $VALUE)" >> output.file
        else
            echo "$VALUE : this is a wrong value" >> output.file
        fi
    done
EOF
```

However, it does not work and I get several errors :

- `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.`. I suspect this is partly due to the fact my remote shell is restricted, and it conflicts with the `echo`.
- $MY_ARRAY seems to be unalocated on remote machine :

  `-rbash: line 5: conditional binary operator expected
  -rbash: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token '^v'
  -rbash: line 5: '   if [[  =~ ^v ]] ; then'`

I am also unsure about how bash will differentiate `$VALUE`, which should be interpretated from my local computer, and `matching_function`, which should be interpretated from the remote one

Comment: Please include in your question your evidence that "it does not work". Are there any error messages, please include those too. Otherwise you're on the right track. Var sub inside of `<< HEREDOCS` is standard , while no attempt to execute that code in the local space is attempted so your `macthing_function` should be executed remotely.

Comment: @shellter I expanded my example to point out the 2 different errors I get as of now

Comment: make small tests and get so you understand difference between `ssh x@y.com '/bin/ls -l $VAL'`, vs `ssh x@y.com "/bin/ls -ls $VAL"`. Then add `match_func` to the mix. Anything that works inside of `"..."` will work in a `<<HEREDOC` unless you invoke "hard" quoting like `<<'HEREDOC'`, which gives you the same behavior as `..com '/bin/ls -l $VAL'`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter thanks for the tips. I've played with the ssh quotes a bit, but still encouter a problem when doing stuff like : `ssh x@y "VAL=\$(match_func arg1)`. I can't attribute the result to a local variable, rather it creates a remote variable and allocate the result of the function to it (I've tried other syntaxes to try and obtain this result, to no avail)

Comment: So did you get any results from `ssh x@y "VAL=\$(match_func arg1); echo \${VAL}"` And, more importantly, and again returning to the idea of small steps, what happens when you do `ssh x@y "match_func StringArg"` ? Good luck!

Comment: @shellter Both work. However I can't take the returned value back to my local computer. The value only exists on the remote computer

Comment: Rereading your question, and with your added error info, the key problem seems to be that MY_ARRAY is not getting expanded for the `<<HEREDOC` (because error msg shows that $VALUE is empty). Again with small test cases AND with your local shell debugging turned on with `set -vx`  AND remote debugging turn on with at `set -vx;` preceding any commands sent via ssh, you should be able to see where this is failing. It looks very close as is.

Comment: BUT I can tell you from building some pretty complicated remote-over-the-wire-functions for ssh, that the time-to-get-working rises exponentially with the complexity of the code you're trying to send over-the-wire. Hence my refrain of get the simple stuff work first ;-). At work now, will probably not be able to look at this again until tomorrow afternoon. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if it's been some time, I'll answer my question with the solution I used for my problem.

After struggling a LOT with the combination of heredocs and SSH, I came up with a partial solution :

```
MY_ARRAY=('value1' 'value2' 'value3' 'wrongValue)
ssh admin@machine -T << EOF >output.file
    for VALUE in "${MY_ARRAY[@]}"
    do
        if [[ \$VALUE =~ ^v ]] ; then
            echo "\$VALUE : \$(matching_function \$VALUE)"
        else
            echo "\$VALUE : this is a wrong value"
        fi
    done
EOF
```

I used `$` before local variables, and `\$` before remote ones. This is due to heredoc behaviour, as `bash` interpretes every varaible preceeded by a `$` before executing the content of the heredoc.

The `>output.file` allowed me to catch the output of the ssh command and do some postprocessing. However, I never found out how to allocate a variable out of the `<<EOF ... EOF`, but I guess this is more of a heredoc issue.

I'll accept my answer as of now, but I'll be glad if anyone could clarify why/if it is impossible to allocate a variable from the heredoc to the outside.

Answer (score 3):

`man ssh`:

> If `command` is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell.

People might tell you that you can force allocating a pseudo-tty by using various amounts of `-t` which does work but comes with the side effect of running a login shell, therefore it might be better to just do

```
ssh admin@machine bash <<EOF
    ...
    #some instructions
    ...
EOF
```

instead to force not executing a login shell.